# Spring MVC log4j2 separate log file for each webapp by bundle key exist or not

Tags: spring-mvc, log4j2

In a Java Spring MVC webapplication, I'm using and configured log4j2 on Tomcat 9. Many war are installed on the server. The default log4j2.xml in under Tomcat (not inside webapplication war).
I want to have separate log by application. The way I want to use to define the log name file is by a bundle file under each war. But some war will be haven't this bundle file.

- war 1: WEB-INF/classes/application.properties with keyname applicationName with value app1
- war 2: WEB-INF/classes/application.properties with keyname applicationName with value app2
- war 3: no bundle file

Environment: Java Spring 5 MVC webapplication (not spring boot)

Server: Tomcat 9 with jdk 11

Lib under tomcat: log4j2-web-2.17.2 (not inside the war, it's a requirement)

Default log4j2 xml file under tomcat/conf/log4j2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="info" strict="true" name="TomcatConfig" packages="org.apache.logging.log4j" monitorInterval="10">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="logPattern">%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%-p] [%t] %C:%L %M - %m%n</Property>       
        <Property name="appName">${bundle:application:applicationName}</Property>
        <Property name="filenameApp">${sys:catalina.base}/logs/${appName:-tomcat}.log</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Filter type="ThresholdFilter" level="info" />
    <Appenders>     
        <Appender type="File" name="fileAppAppender" fileName="${filenameApp}">
            <Layout type="PatternLayout" pattern="${logPattern}" />
        </Appender>     
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">         
            <AppenderRef ref="fileAppAppender" />           
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

It works for app1 and app2 but for app3 it generate an error (and it's normal):

`WARN Error looking up ResourceBundle [application]. java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name application, locale en_GB`

All application works, log are ok in speparate for file for app1 (app1.log) and app2 (app2.log).

How can manage to avoid this error? How can use a try/catch or an if exist in log4j2.xml?